# Google Cast Chrome sender app isn't registering on iOS

Tags: ios, google-chrome, google-cast

Google Chrome browser on iOS isn't registering my Chromecast sender application. This is a recent problem (last few weeks) as it was working as expected before.

Currently works as expected on Android, MacOS, and Windows desktop. Appears to be only on iPhone/iPad that the chrome browser isn't launching on the chromecast window event.

```
<script>
    var appID = 'appId';
    window['__onGCastApiAvailable'] = function(isAvailable) {
      if (isAvailable) {
        console.log('cast available')
        setupCast();
      }
    };
</script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/cv/js/sender/v1/cast_sender.js?loadCastFramework=1"></script>
```

Neither the above console log or one I have inside the setup cast function are getting called.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Did your received any errors in your logs?

Comment: Nope, no logs showed up in my connected console. Just would not fire.

Comment: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=872050&q=ios%20chromecast&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified

Comment: @LeonNicholls -- thanks for the response!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else runs into this issue, it's because it's been removed from iPhone/Chrome as of early February 2019, with the original task dating back to November 2018:

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=872050&q=ios%20chromecast&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified

Thanks to the Google Developer Relations Team (esp. Leon Nicholls) for highlighting this.